# How to edit the default 'New Snippet' template in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: sublimetext2, code-snippets

I create a lot of snippets for Sublime Text 2. I always use the optional tab trigger and never use the trigger scope. I'd like to edit the 'New Snippet' template so I don't have to uncomment and delete these respective options every time.

**TL;DR - Where does this default 'New Snippet' text come from so I can change it:**

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
Hello, ${1:this} is a ${2:snippet}.
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <!-- <tabTrigger>hello</tabTrigger> -->
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <!-- <scope>source.python</scope> -->
</snippet>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new snippet command is defined in **Packages/Default/new_templates.py**.  Edit it there.  (I found it by opening [Packages](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/basic_concepts.html#the-data-directory) in sublime and searching for one of it's lines.

```
class NewSnippetCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):
        v = self.window.new_file()
        v.settings().set('default_dir',
            os.path.join(sublime.packages_path(), 'User'))
        v.settings().set('default_extension', 'sublime-snippet')
        v.set_syntax_file('Packages/XML/XML.tmLanguage')

        template = """<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
Hello, \${1:this} is a \${2:snippet}.
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <!-- <tabTrigger>hello</tabTrigger> -->
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <!-- <scope>source.python</scope> -->
</snippet>
"""
```

Comment: It would be smart to make your edits to a separate plugin so that your changes don't get removed on an update.  You can see how I did it here: https://github.com/dsandstrom/CustomNewSnippet.  I also made a menu item for my plugin.