# Editing Sublime Text 3's snippet template

Tags: sublimetext, code-snippets

Every time I create a new Sublime Text 3 snippet, I make the same changes (in my case: replace "Hello, ${1:this} is a ${2:snippet}." with content that I have just copied from a file, delete the comments around the `tabTrigger` and the `scope`, set the scope to "text.html").

Is there a way to edit the template itself, so that this is all of this is already done (apart from pasting the copied content) when I create a new snippet?

Comment: This question asks about Sublime text 3, but you should be able to use this answer that is about Sublime Text 2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16325001/how-to-edit-the-default-new-snippet-template-in-sublime-text-2

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16325001/how-to-edit-the-default-new-snippet-template-in-sublime-text-2).
If you're on a Mac:

1. Open Terminal
2. Enter `unzip -j "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/MacOS/Packages/Default.sublime-package" new_templates.py -d .` into the terminal
3. Enter `"/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" new_templates.py` into the terminal
4. Scroll down to bottom of new_templates.py inside Sublime, and make changes
5. Save the file, close the tab, and quit sublime
6. Enter `zip "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/MacOS/Packages/Default.sublime-package" new_templates.py` into the terminal to reupdate the Default.sublime-package with your modified new_templates.py

Now if you reopen Sublime, go to the Tools menu, and click New Snippet..., you should be able to see your modified snippet!

With help from:

[Extract only a specific file from a zipped archive to a given directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14120/extract-only-a-specific-file-from-a-zipped-archive-to-a-given-directory)

[How to update one file in a zip archive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799553/how-to-update-one-file-in-a-zip-archive)